# Array contains all elements in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, coffeescript

Been trying to figure out how to do this for a while, but haven't had any success yet. If I have 2 arrays like this:

```
array1 = [
    { name: 'John', age : 25},
    { name: 'Jane', age : 58}
]
array2 = [
    { name: 'Jane', age : 58},
    { name: 'John', age : 25}
]
```

How can I chech if `array1` contains all the elements of `array2`? Note - the ordering doesn't matter, I want to be able to write something like this:

```
if array1.containsAll array2
    console.log 'array1 contains all of the elements in array2'
else
    console.log 'array1 does not contain all of the elements in array2'
```

I've tried using the `contains` function, but I get an error like this:

```
Object .... has no method 'contains'
```

Comment: are you willing to consider a utility library, like underscore to get object comparison and composition? http://jsfiddle.net/no02qybh/

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. alandarev's solution is close but you can't meaningfully compare the contents of objects using == (or ===) in JavaScript so you'd have to manually compare the values. You can hide some of the nastiness using a utility library (such as Underscore) but that's just shuffling the deck chairs around and hiding the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this method has good performance, but it should be pretty robust, and is super simple to understand...

```
# sort function to marshall data into consistent format
sortfunc = (a,b)-> JSON.stringify(a) < JSON.stringify(b)

# if serialized, sorted arrays are equal, then all items are present
if JSON.stringify(array1.sort(sortfunc)) == JSON.stringify(array2.sort(sortfunc))
    console.log "same"
else
    console.log "different"
```

n.b. caveat is that order of object keys may or may not be significant, depending on whether JS engine respects object index order (JS spec states it is not required)

Comment: But there's no guarantee that `{ name: 'John', age : 25}` will be `'{"name":"John","age":25}'` when JSONified rather than `'{"age":25,"name":"John"}'` and there's no guarantee that two `JSON.stringify` calls will put the keys in the same order. If you need the keys to be in a specific order (and you do), then you have to flatten them to arrays yourself.

Comment: Also, a sorting comparison function does not return a boolean value, it should return a positive, negative, or zero value to cover the three possibilities.